# Given a list of integer rectangle areas, find all integer rectangles that they can tile

Tags: algorithms, reference-request

> Is there an efficient algorithm that takes in a list (multiset) of integer rectangle areas and finds all possible integer rectangle tilings?
>
> Every integer rectangle area in the list (multiset) must be used exactly once (corresponds to exactly one rectangle).

For example, if we were given $$(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 18, 1, 1, 20, 1)$$
then one possible integer rectangle tiling is:

[image]

which uses the given list to tile a $11\times 12$ rectangle.

So far, I've found [What rectangles can a set of rectangles tile?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/285018/88524) on MO, and am trying to track down and adapt the references to my problem.

A similar but different problem is [Filling rectangles with integer-sided squares](http://int-e.eu/%7Ebf3/squares/).

Comment: Can each area in the list only be used once for a single piece? That is, no copies? Must each area be used, or can some be left out?

Comment: @orlp Every area must be used exactly once. (Notice multiple copies of area $1$ in the example list.)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to incorporate the information into the question, rather than leaving a comment here.  We want the question to be understandable without having to read the comments.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer assumes that you only allow the tiles to have integer sides.**

There are always some trivial tilings, in which the rectangle being tiled has either a single row or a single column. Counting the number of these is simple combinatorics. Let us show that deciding whether there are any other tilings is NP-complete ([under randomized reductions, or assuming some number-theoretic conjectures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/is-there-a-polynomial-time-algorithm-to-find-a-prime-larger-than-n)). It is clearly in NP. To show that it is NP-hard, we reduce from PARTITION. An instance of PARTITION is a multiset of positive integers, and the problem is to determine whether it can be partitioned into two multisets with equal sum.

---

We start by showing that PARTITION is NP-hard even if all parts are odd and the total sum is divisible by 4. Let us first ignore the latter requirement. Given an instance $S = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of PARTITION, construct an instance of the new problem with $S' = \{2nx_1+1,\ldots,2nx_n+1\} \cup \{1^n\}$ (here $1^n$ mean $n$ many $1$s).

If the original instance can be partitioned into two equal parts, say $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$ and $\{x_{m+1},\ldots,x_n\}$, then so can the new instance. Indeed, consider the multiset $\{2nx_1+1,\ldots,2nx_m+1\}$, together with $n-m$ many $1$s. This multiset sums to $2n(x_1 + \cdots + x_m) + m + (n-m) = 2n(x_1 + \cdots + x_m) + n$. Similarly, the remaining numbers sum to $2n(x_{m+1} + \cdots + x_n) + (n-m) + m = 2n(x_{m+1} + \cdots + x_n) = n$, which is identical.

Conversely, suppose that $S'$ can be partitioned into two equal parts, say one of them consisting of $2nx_1+1,\ldots,2nx_m+1$ together with $r$ many $1$s. It follows that
$$ 2n(x_1 + \cdots + x_m) + m + r = 2n(x_{m+1} + \cdots + x_n) + (n-m) + (n-r), $$
and so
$$ 2n(x_1 + \cdots + x_m - x_{m+1} - \cdots - x_n) = (n-2m) + (n-2r). $$
Since $1 \leq m \leq n-1$ and $0 \leq r \leq n$, the right-hand side is in the range $[-(2n-2),(2n-2)]$. Since the left-hand side is a multiple of $2n$, we conclude that the right-hand size is zero, and so $x_1 + \cdots + x_m = x_{m+1} + \cdots + x_n$.

Let us now attend to the sum of $S'$. If $S$ sums to $2R$ then $S'$ sums to
$$
2n \cdot 2R + 2n = 2n(2R+1).
$$
Therefore if $n$ is even, then we are done. Otherwise, we can replace $n$ with $n+1$ throughout (equivalently, add a zero to $S$).

---

We now reduce the PARTITION variant to the tiling problem.
Let $S$ be an instance of PARTITION in which all numbers are odd and the sum is $2T$, where $T$ is even. Let $p$ be a prime in $(2T,3T)$. Notice that $S \cup \{p-T,p-T\}$ can be partitioned into two equal halves iff $S$ can (this is since $2(p-T)$ is larger than half the total sum, which is $[2T+2(p-T)]/2 = p$). Moreover, since $p$ is odd and $T$ is even, $p-T$ is odd.

Let $q \in (2p,3p)$ be a prime, and consider the instance $S \cup \{p-T,p-T,pq\}$. If $S$ can be partitioned into two equal halves, then we can tile a rectangle of dimensions $p \times (q+2)$ by taking a rectangle of dimensions $p \times q$ and adding two more columns corresponding to the two equal halves of $S \cup \{p-T,p-T\}$.

Conversely, suppose that $S \cup \{p-T,p-T,pq\}$ can tile some rectangle. Since $p,q$ are prime, the rectangle of area $pq$ must have dimensions $1 \times pq$ or $p \times q$ (up to switching the axes). In the former case, since all remaining numbers add up to $2p < pq$, we end up with a trivial tiling. In the latter case, since $2p < q$, the remaining numbers are not enough to fill any rows, and so we conclude that the tiled rectangle must have exactly $p$ rows. Since the remaining numbers add up to $2p$, they must tile a $p \times 2$ rectangle (or two $p \times 1$ rectangles, which is a stronger requirement). The remaining numbers are all odd, and so must correspond to rectangles with a single column. This is only possible if they can be partitioned into two equal parts.